# GenericRowWithSchema ClassCastException in Spark 3 Scala UDF for Array data

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am writing a Spark 3 UDF to mask an attribute in an Array field.

My data (in parquet, but shown in a JSON format):

```
{"conditions":{"list":[{"element":{"code":"1234","category":"ABC"}},{"element":{"code":"4550","category":"EDC"}}]}}
```

case class:

```
case class MyClass(conditions: Seq[MyItem])
case class MyItem(code: String, category: String)
```

Spark code:

```
val data = Seq(MyClass(conditions = Seq(MyItem("1234", "ABC"), MyItem("4550", "EDC"))))
import spark.implicits._

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val ds = rdd.toDF().as[MyClass]

val maskedConditions: Column = updateArray.apply(col("conditions"))

ds.withColumn("conditions", maskedConditions)
  .select("conditions")
  .show(2)
```

Tried the following UDF function.

UDF code:

```
def updateArray = udf((arr: Seq[MyItem]) => {
    for (i <- 0 to arr.size - 1) {
      // Line 3
      val a = arr(i).asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema]
      val a = arr(i)
      println(a.getAs[MyItem](0))

      // TODO: How to make code = "XXXX" here
      // a.code = "XXXX"
    }

    arr
  })
```

Goal:
I need to set 'code' field value in each array item to "XXXX" in a UDF.

Issue:
I am unable to modify the array fields.

Also I get the following error if remove the line 3 in the UDF (cast to GenericRowWithSchema).

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to MyItem
```

Question: How to capture Array of Structs in a function and how to return a modified array of items?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small json linting error in your data: I assumed that you wanted to close the `[]` square brackets of the `list` array. So, for this example I used the following data (which is the same as yours):

```
{"conditions":{"list":[{"element":{"code":"1234","category":"ABC"}},{"element":{"code":"4550","category":"EDC"}}]}}
```

You don't need UDFs for this: a simple `map` operation will be sufficient! The following code does what you want:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

case class MyItem(code: String, category: String)
case class MyElement(element: MyItem)
case class MyList(list: Seq[MyElement])
case class MyClass(conditions: MyList)

val df = spark.read.json("./someData.json").as[MyClass]

val transformedDF = df.map{
  case (MyClass(MyList(list))) => MyClass(MyList(list.map{
    case (MyElement(item)) => MyElement(MyItem(code = "XXXX", item.category))
  }))
}

transformedDF.show(false)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+--------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|conditions                      |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+--------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
|[[[[XXXX, ABC]], [[XXXX, EDC]]]]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
+--------------------------------+
```

As you see, we're doing some simple pattern matching on the case classes we've defined and successfully renaming all of the `code` fields' values to `"XXXX"`. If you want to get a json back, you can call the `to_json` function like so:

```
transformedDF.select(to_json($"conditions")).show(false)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                          
|structstojson(conditions)                                                                           |                                                                                                                                                                          
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                          
|{"list":[{"element":{"code":"XXXX","category":"ABC"}},{"element":{"code":"XXXX","category":"EDC"}}]}|                                                                                                                                                                          
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally a very small remark about the data. If you have any control over how the data gets made, I would add the following suggestions:

- The `conditions` JSON object seems to have no function in here, since it just contains a single array called `list`. Consider making the `conditions` object the array, which would allow you to discard the `list` name. That would simpify your structure
- The `element` object does nothing, except containing a single item. Consider removing 1 level of abstraction there too.
- With these suggestions, your data would contain the same information but look something like:

```
{"conditions":[{"code":"1234","category":"ABC"},{"code":"4550","category":"EDC"}]}
```

With these suggestions, you would also remove the need of the `MyElement` and the `MyList` case classes! But very often we're not in control over what data we receive so this is just a small disclaimer :)

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: After your addition of simplified data according to the above suggestions, the task gets even easier. Again, you only need a `map` operation here:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

case class MyItem(code: String, category: String)
case class MyClass(conditions: Seq[MyItem])

val data = Seq(MyClass(conditions = Seq(MyItem("1234", "ABC"), MyItem("4550", "EDC"))))

val df = data.toDF.as[MyClass]

val transformedDF = df.map{
  case MyClass(conditions) => MyClass(conditions.map{
    item => MyItem("XXXX", item.category)
  })
}
transformedDF.show(false)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
+--------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|conditions                |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+--------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
|[[XXXX, ABC], [XXXX, EDC]]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The data I posted is in parquet format. I just posted a single row for simplicity. Also I am looking for a UDF as this is part of a big application and I am just dealing with arrays. Either way, I will look into data generation part. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the code to add data declaration.

Comment: I've added an edit section at the end to show what you can do with your new data.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to find a simple solution with Spark 3.1+ as new features are added in this new Spark version.

Updated code:

```
val data = Seq(
          MyClass(conditions = Seq(MyItem("1234", "ABC"), MyItem("234", "KBC"))),
          MyClass(conditions = Seq(MyItem("4550", "DTC"), MyItem("900", "RDT")))
        )
import spark.implicits._
    
val ds = data.toDF()
    
val updatedDS = ds.withColumn(
       "conditions",
       transform(
         col("conditions"),
         x => x.withField("code", updateArray(x.getField("code")))))
    
updatedDS.show()
```

UDF:

```
def updateArray = udf((oldVal: String) => {
   if(oldVal.contains("1234"))
      "XXX"
   else
      oldVal
})
```